# flash[:notice] not working when using AJAX in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, notice

I've tried different variants of make flash[:notice] working without reload.

Stackoverflow gave me this - [How do you handle Rail's flash with Ajax requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/366311/how-do-you-handle-rails-flash-with-ajax-requests), but I can't find solution, that worked for me.

For example, added to my controller:

```
def create
  @entry = Entry.new(params[:entry])
  respond_to do |format|
  if @entry.save
    format.html { redirect_to @entry, notice: 'Entry was successfully created.' }
    format.js {
  flash.now[:notice] = 'Website was successfully created.'
 render action: 'create'
}
  else
    format.html { render action: "new" }
    format.js { render action: "new" }
  end
  end
end
```

**create.js**

```
   $('<%= j render @website %>').appendTo('#websites').hide().fadeIn();
  $(".alert").html("<%= escape_javascript(flash[:notice]) %>"); $(".alert").show(300);
  $("#new_website")[0].reset();
```

but it didn't work.

Can someone tell me understandable full solution, that worked for him ?

Comment: and how your view template `create.js.erb` looks like?  You should use your current flash there.

Comment: Looks good, try to use firebug to see ajax response from your server and debug js code.

Comment: no errors related with form. only errors related with Chosen plugin.

Comment: I should add some observer in FireBug console ?

Comment: You should perform AJAX request, inspect server's response and see how output looks like, after that try to execute same JS code inside firebug console.

Comment: have you checked out unobtrusive flash gem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you make a typo on your js template filename? it should be create.js.erb but not create.js
and please strictly follow the https://stackoverflow.com/a/8873592/557863 , then make your changes on it.

Answer (score 0):

You're submitting new entries via Ajax, so you shouldn't use the flash -- it's intended for redirect responses, but you're not redirecting. To indicate success or failure, you'd need to write that into your JavaScript response.