# How to get flash message instantly after an ajax call?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am using rails 3 version, after an ajax call, I am not able to display flash message.It displays only after when user manually reloads a page.

Any advice?

Comment: [check the link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/366311/how-do-you-handle-rails-flash-with-ajax-requests)

Answer (score 0):

Use [flash.now](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#the-flash):

`flash.now[:notice] = 'available in same request'`

Comment: I tried with your suggestion with controller, but it cannot display any flash even if page reloads!

Comment: @Pez have a look at Nithin's comment. That might be what you're looking for.