# Handle Rails flash messages after AJAX calls using ReactJS

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, reactjs

Several posts describe displaying flash messages after AJAX calls (for instance, [Rails doesn't display flash messages after ajax call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21032465/rails-doesnt-display-flash-messages-after-ajax-call) and [How do you handle Rail's flash with Ajax requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/366311/how-do-you-handle-rails-flash-with-ajax-requests)).

I'm using [ReactJS](http://facebook.github.io/react/index.html) with [react-rails](https://github.com/reactjs/react-rails) and want to do this, and want to take advantage of React's dynamic display rendering.

So I'm answering my own question of how to render flash messages after AJAX calls when using ReactJS below as a way to answer others who might encounter this and get any advice for improving it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This implementation is based largely on the other SO posts on this subject (see references in question).  The code assumes Rails 4.x with the asset pipeline, HAML for the views, Bootstrap for styling, and use of the [react-rails](https://github.com/reactjs/react-rails) gem.

(*update*: a slightly longer discussion can be found at [my blog](http://rdnewman.github.io/coding/2014/11/16/reactjs-flash.html)).

**Layout**
Here's the `app/views/layouts/application.html.haml` file:

```
!!!
%html
  %head
    %title
      Demo

    = stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true
    = javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true
    = csrf_meta_tags

  %body
    %div.container
      %div#flash_messages
      = yield
```

Note that the `div` has an id of `#flash_messages`.  The placement of this container div determines where the flash message appear.

**Controller**
The private routine below simply converts the native array-of-arrays uses to be parseable JSON in the header.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  after_filter :flash_to_http_header

private
  def flash_to_http_header
    return unless request.xhr?
    return if flash.empty?
    response.headers['X-FlashMessages'] = flash.to_hash.to_json
    flash.discard  # don't want the flash to appear when you reload page
  end
end
```

**Javascript (ReactJS)**
The following javascript is made up of a React class, a global function to process flash messages out of the response header, and a JQuery handler for completion of AJAX calls.  It's put into a single JX file (I used `app/assets/javascripts/react/flash_messages.js.jsx`) to keep the relevant JS functionality together.  I discuss this more below.

```
/** @jsx React.DOM */

var FlashMessages = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {messages: this.props.messages};
  },

  messages: function (messageArray) {
    this.replaceState({messages: messageArray});
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className='flash_messages_component'>
        {this.state.messages.map(function(message, index) {
          _level = message[0];
          _text  = message[1];
          return (
            <div key={index} className={this._flash_class(_level)}>
              {_text}
            </div>
          );
        }.bind(this))}
      </div>
    )
  },

  _flash_class: function(level) {
    var _result = 'alert alert-error';
    if (level === 'notice') {
      _result = 'alert alert-info';
    } else if (level === 'success') {
      _result = 'alert alert-success';
    } else if (level === 'error') {
      _result = 'alert alert-error';
    } else if (level === 'alert') {
      _result = 'alert alert-error';
    }
    return _result;
  }

});

function handleFlashMessagesHeader(node, xhr) {
  var _message_array = new Array();
  var _raw_messages = xhr.getResponseHeader("X-FlashMessages")
  if (_raw_messages) {
    var _json_messages = JSON.parse(_raw_messages);
    count = 0
    for (var key in _json_messages) {
      _message_array[count] = new Array();
      _message_array[count][0] = key;
      _message_array[count][1] = _json_messages[key];
      count += 1;
    }
  }
  node.messages(_message_array);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  var dummy = new Array();
  var flashDiv = React.render(<FlashMessages messages={dummy} />, $('#flash_messages')[0]);

  $(document).ajaxComplete(function(event, xhr, settings) {
    handleFlashMessagesHeader(flashDiv, xhr);
  });
});
```

The `FlashMessages` React class does a few things.  First, it moves the props into state.  Generally this would be an anti-pattern, but doing so enables non-React code to trigger changes when needed.  The `messages` function is that trigger and is meant to be called by external JS code.  The main processing for `render` assumes the Rails flash-native array-of-2-element-arrays data structure to keep processing to a minimum and allow the component to be used directly from a view instead of just AJAX calls.  Finally, the local `_flash_class` method supports Bootstrap styling (which of course could be adjusted for other styling as desired).

The `handleFlashMessagesHeader` is a global function for converting the JSON back to an array-of-arrays done by the Rails controller filter method.  Note that it takes the DOM element with the id marker from the Rails app view/layout.

The last section is meant to be run on page load and so depends on JQuery ready.  The `React.render` (formally `React.renderComponent`) is saved to a global variable to allow direct calling into the `FlashMessages` object's `message` method (the `dummy` array used is just to seed an empty flashes array when first invoked -- this could probably be handled within the React class too by a null test).  Whenever `ajaxComplete` is triggered, the `handleFlashMessageHeader` function is invoked and passed the React object for updating.

**Non-AJAX**
Because the React class assumes native array-of-arrays, the view could have simply called a

```
= react-component 'FlashMessages', flash, :div
```

instead to display it, but then of course it's of less use since dynamic response isn't supported.  However, the ability to invoke it either way gives more flexibility for some use cases.

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't able to get @rdnewman's answer to work with Rails 5 and react-rails 1.9.0 (corresponds to React 15.3.0). I think something changed in React that doesn't allow external access to functions, so the call to `.messages()` in `handleFlashMessagesHeader()` doesn't work (function not found).

I adapted the answer to something that works for me. I'm just learning React, so there may be a better way, but here's what I've got:

`app/controllers/application_controller.rb`

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  after_action :flash_to_http_header, if: -> { request.xhr? }

  private

  def flash_to_http_header
    return if flash.empty?
    response.headers['X-FlashMessages'] = flash.to_hash.to_json
    flash.discard
  end
end
```

`app/assets/javascripts/components/flash_messages.js.coffee`:

```
@FlashMessages = React.createClass
  getInitialState: ->
    messages: @props.data
  getDefaultProps: ->
    messages: {}
  componentDidMount: ->
    $(document).ajaxComplete ((event, xhr, settings) ->
      header_messages = xhr.getResponseHeader('X-FlashMessages')
      messages = {}
      if header_messages
        messages = JSON.parse(header_messages)
      @replaceState {messages: messages}
    ).bind(this)
  messageClass: (messageType) ->
    if messageType == 'notice'
      return 'alert alert-warning'
    if messageType == 'success'
      return 'alert alert-success'
    return 'alert alert-error'
  render: ->
    React.DOM.div
      className: 'flash-messages'
      for messageType of @state.messages
        React.DOM.div
          className: @messageClass(messageType)
          key: messageType
          @state.messages[messageType]
```

`app/views/layouts/application.html.erb`

```
<%= react_component 'FlashMessages', { data: flash.to_hash } %>
```

This will render standard flash messages when the page loads, and update/replace them after any Ajax request. If you're using the `react-rails` gem, you can just drop the file into the `components` directory and everything should work.