# Rails flash with AJAX request without page refresh

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, reactjs

Im hoping there is a cleaning way of getting flash messages to work in an ajax call using React. Been [looking on the web](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21032465/rails-doesnt-display-flash-messages-after-ajax-call) and, honestly, Im sure it can be done without much added code.

```
def my_method
 [...]

 flash[:success] = "Yea bouy."
 if request.xhr?
    render :json => {
                        :order => true,
                    }
 end
end
```

I'm not doing a page redirect and was wondering how to get a simple flash to show. Anwers around showing adding more methods. Could I have the flash code within my method? Something like:

```
def my_method
 [...]
 if request.xhr?
    render :json => {
                        :order => true,
                    }
 end
 return flash[:success] = "Yea bouy." # Only works when page refreshes.
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Flash works on page reload, so in case of an Ajax request you can send the message back as a response and show it using JS. Or, you can render a `js.erb` template and inside that show the message using JS.

Hope that helps!

Comment: So that's the only way?

Comment: I guess yes, thats the only way!