# Need a way for Rails controller to return flash messages in response to AJAX request

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

As an inexperienced but quick-learning Rails developer, I want to write a controller after-filter that checks for AJAX requests and returns some HTML in a custom header that can be used by the response handler to display any flash messages.

For consistency and conformance to DRY, I want to create that partial HTML using the same app/views/layouts/_messages.html.erb(.haml) that Rails generated.

After viewing several posts, my solution is thus:

```
  # adapted from http://stackoverflow.com/a/2729454/270511
  def flash_to_headers
    return unless request.xhr?
    response.headers['X-flash'] = render_to_string partial: 'layouts/messages.html'
    flash.discard  # don't want the flash to appear when you reload page
  end
```

This actually returns the desired headers, but also [throws an exception](https://gist.github.com/lsiden/8773448).

Subsequent searching revealed several posts where the respondents claimed that calling render_to_string from an after-filter is not supported.

One alternate solution I am thinking of is to render layouts/navigation.html a second time from views/layouts/application.html.haml, but enclosed in a div where display=none.  To accomplish this with the same template, I will have to add some dummy place-holder messages to flash[:notice, :warn, and :error] because otherwise _messages.html.haml was written not to render sections when there are no related messages.  Then I can use the placeholders as templates to clone and fill in with flash messages returned by subsequent AJAX requests.

While this might work, I think it is ugly and has an unpleasant smell.  (I am inexperienced at Rails, but not at software development!)  It may be possible that I have missed something due to my lack of experience with Rails (and lack of available mentors).  If so, I will be grateful if someone can point out a cleaner way of accomplishing my goal.

If not, I will re-post this to the issues list for rails on Github.  I think that displaying flash messages to indicate some feedback from an AJAX request to the end-user is a common enough use-case that Rails should support it better.

Comment: Is there a reason why you would not consider using the standard unobtrusive Javascript where you use format.js in the response in your action in Rails, and call a common JS function that flashes a message from the create.js.erb, update.js.erb, etc that is returned from each Ajax call?

Comment: I think I'm already doing something like that now.  The logic for creating the placeholders for the AJAX flash messages is in layouts/application.html.haml and it does it by rendering the generated _message.html.haml partial with placeholder messages.  The Javascript that clones the placeholders and displays the received message are currently local to the Ajax response handler, but soon I'll isolate it in a separate file and then package the whole thing in it's own gem for review and improvement by the community.  Thanks for the thought.

Answer (score 0):

I consider my AJAX requests as API calls, and therefore I only send minimal information in my message headers, and only send the most relevant error message

*application_controller.rb*

```
return unless request.xhr?

if type = priority_flash # Method that returns most relevant message
  response.headers['X-Message'] = flash[type]
  response.headers['X-Message-Type'] = type.to_s

  flash.discard  # don't want the flash to appear when you reload page  
end
```

The job of rendering the error message should belong to the javascript files

*some_js_file.js*

```
// AJAX callbacks
$(document).ajaxComplete(function(e, request, opts) { 
    fireFlash(request.getResponseHeader('X-Message'), request.getResponseHeader('X-Message-Type')); 
});

$(document).ajaxError(function(event, jqxhr, settings, thrownError){
    fireFlash("AJAX request failed : " + jqxhr.status + " "+thrownError, "danger")
});

/* AJAX Flash messages */
function fireFlash(content, type){
    if (content === null){
        return
    }
    var alert_type;
    switch(type){
        case "alert":
        case "danger":
        case "fatal":
        case "error":
            alert_type= "danger"
            break;
        case "success":
        case "notice":
            alert_type= "success"
            break;
        case "warning":
            alert_type= "warning"
        default:
            alert_type= "info"
    }
    $("#flashes").prepend($("<div/>")
        .addClass("alert alert-dismissible alert-ajax alert-"+alert_type)
        .html((decodeURIComponent(escape(content))))
        .append('<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>')
    )
    document.location.href = "#top";
}
```