# Rails flash notice via ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, flash

Long story short, I have a button. On clicking it, I want an ajax request to be triggered which gets flash[:notice] and displays it in a div in$

Here is my shortened view:

```
 <input type="button" id="search" value="display"/>

 <div id="notice">

 </div>
```

My ajax request in the view:

```
$("#search").submit(function(){
                            $.ajax({
                                type: "POST",
                                url: //url to my show action
                                success: function(data){
                                      /*$("#notice").html("<%= flash[:notice] %>");
                                        $("#content").html(data);*/
                                }
                            });
                            return false;
                    });
```

My controller:

```
def HomeController <  ActionController::Base
  def index

  end

  def show
    respond_to do |format|
    format.js {  flash[:notice] = "" + count.to_s + " results found for " + params[:query][:search_key] + "" }
    end
    #render :partial => 'search'
  end
end
```

My show.js.erb

```
#app/views/dashboard_home/show.js.erb
$("#notice").html("<%=j flash[:notice] %>");

$("#content").html("<%=j render partial: "search" %>");
```

The problem is when I click on button, the notice is displayed fine. But the same notice persists on the next clicks too. The search partial contains the table Please help!

Answer (score 34):

Here is an example that I got working, thanks to Rich Peck's answer.  I needed to use `flash.now` to make sure the flash notice didn't persist.

AJAX trigger in the view:

```
<%= link_to "Email report", users_path, remote: true %>
```

Controller:

```
# app/controllers/users_controller
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def index
    # do some things here

    respond_to do |format|
      format.js { flash.now[:notice] = "Here is my flash notice" }
    end
  end
end
```

Rendered view:

```
# app/views/users/index.js.erb
$("#flash").html('<%= j render partial: "shared/notice_banner" %>');
```

where the flash notice is displayed in the layout:

```
# app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
<div id="flash">
  <% if notice.present? %>
    <%= render partial: "shared/notice_banner" %>
  <% end %>
</div>


# app/views/shared/_notice_banner.html.erb
<div data-alert class="alert-box">
  <%= notice %>
  <a href="#" class="close">&times;</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 25):

**Sessions**

> the same notice persists on the next clicks too

This is caused by the `flash` being [stored in the `session` variable of Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#the-flash):

> The flash is a special part of the session which is cleared with each
>   request. This means that values stored there will only be available in
>   the next request, which is useful for passing error messages etc.

The problem you have is that since I don't think ajax counts as a new request (need reference for this), the data will persist into the next time you request via HTTP.

--

**Fix**

I would initially try this:

```
def show
    respond_to do |format|
        format.js {  flash[:notice] = "my secret number "+rand(0,5)+" !" }
    end
end
```

The main problem you have is you're processing the `flash` variable in your JS using the `ERB` preprocessor. This is an issue as it means you won't be able to use asset precompile to help it work.

After looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/366311/how-do-you-handle-rails-flash-with-ajax-requests), why not try using the [`after_filter` callback](http://www.whatcodecraves.com/articles/2008/12/13/rails-flash-with-ajax), like this:

```
#app/controllers/home_controller.rb
Class Home < ActionController::Base
   after_filter { flash.discard if request.xhr? }, only: :show

    def show
        respond_to do |format|
            format.js {  flash[:notice] = "my secret number "+rand(0,5)+" !" }
        end
    end
end
```

--

**Update**

You should include the `success` functionality in your `show.js.erb`:

```
#app/views/home/show.js.erb
$("#notice").html("<%= flash[:notice] %>");
```

This means you can remove the whole `ajax` call from the `application.js`, and replace with the `remote: true` for your search form:

```
#app/views/search/index.html.erb
<%= form_tag home_show_path, remote: true %>
```

The reason this works is because when you use the `format.js` respond block, Rails will load the `[action].js.erb` file in your views. Considering this only happens *after* the action has been completed, it's equivalent to the `success` function of your ajax.

By doing this, you'll be able to remove the entire `ajax` function from your `application.js`, and replace with the UJS version, as described above

Comment: thnx..but how should i access the flash notice in the ajax success function?

Comment: You'll be better creating `show.js.erb` in your `views/home` folder - this will load that file with the `ERB` preprocessor, consequently allowing you to show the `flash` message. Since this file is exclusive of the `asset pipeline`, it won't get lost when you precompile the assets :)

Comment: so shud i put the whole ajax fn in the show.js.erb?

Comment: Well all you can hope for now is a miracle!

Comment: I joke...... you need to give me information. A response; is it not firing? Is the Ajax working or not?

Comment: Don't give up that easily. Tell me what is happening - I want to fix this

Comment: the ajax works fine...i get the search results but i dont get the flash notice saying "these many records were found"..i wont give up...

Comment: Okay - have you used the show.js.erb? What about your ajax- just using `remote: true` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54827/discussion-between-rich-peck-and-santino-sonny-corleone).

Comment: but do i need to put the full ajax function in show.js.erb?ajax has remote:true