# How to display flash messages, on successful ajax, at the top of my page, without refreshing?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, flash, error-handling

My bookmarks index page is essentially a single page application. When I submit the form for a new bookmark at the bottom of my page, I want the page to not have to refresh and display `"Bookmark successfully created!"` in the form of a flash message at the top of the page.

In my `application.html.erb` file, I am rendering flash messages:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Text Me Later</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>

<%= render partial: 'layouts/nav' %>

<% flash.each do |key, value| %>
  <% if key == "notice" %>
    <%= content_tag :div, value, class: "text-center alert alert-warning" %>
  <% elsif key == "alert" %>
    <%= content_tag :div, value, class: "text-center alert alert-danger" %>
  <% else %>
    <%= content_tag :div, value, class: "text-center alert alert-success" %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>

<div class="container">

<%= yield %>

<%= debug(params) if Rails.env.development? %>

</body>
</html>
```

The `create` method in my `bookmarks_controller`:

```
def create
    @bookmark = Bookmark.new bookmark_params
    @bookmark.user_id = current_user.id

    respond_to do |format|
      if @bookmark.save
        flash[:notice] = 'Bookmark was successfully created.'
        format.html { 
          redirect_to user_bookmarks_path
        }
        format.json { 
          render json: @bookmark,
          status: :created, 
          location: @bookmark
        }
        format.js {}
      else
        flash[:error] = "Bookmark could not be created."
        format.html {
          render :index
        }
        format.json {
          render json: @bookmark.errors.full_messages
        }
        format.js {}
      end
    end
  end
```

My `bookmarks` `index.html.erb`file:

```
<h2>All of <%= current_user.first_name %>'s Bookmarks</h2>
<ul id="all-bookmarks">
    <% @bookmarks.each do |bookmark| %>
    <li class="bookmark-div">
            <div><%= bookmark.title %></div>
            <div><%= bookmark.image %></div>
            <div><%= bookmark.description %></div>
            <div><%= bookmark.location %></div>
            <div><%= bookmark.time %></div>
            <div><%= bookmark.date %></div>
            <div><%= bookmark.created_at %></div>
            <div><%= bookmark.updated_at %></div>
            <div><%= bookmark.url %></div>
            <div><%= link_to "Edit", [:edit, bookmark]%></div>
            <div><%= link_to "Delete Bookmark", bookmark, :method => :delete, confirm: 'are you sure?'%></div>
            <div><%= link_to "Add as a reminder" %></div>
    </li>
    <% end %>
</ul>

<h2>Add a bookmark below:</h2>

    <div id="post-new-bookmark">
        <%= simple_form_for [@user, @bookmark], :method => :post, remote: true do |f| %>
            <% if @bookmark.errors.any? %>
             <div id="errorExplanation">
              <h2><%= pluralize(@bookmark.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this post from being saved:</h2>
              <% end %>
            <%= f.input :title %>
            <%= f.input :image %>
            <%= f.input :description %>
            <%= f.input :location %>
            <%= f.input :date %>
            <%= f.button :submit %>
        <% end %>
    </div>
```

`create.js.erb`:

```
$("<%= escape_javascript(flash[:notice]) %>").appendTo("#flash-notice")

$("<%= escape_javascript render(:partial => 'bookmarks/cbookmark', :locals => { :bookmark => @bookmark }) %>").appendTo("#all-bookmarks")
```

My question is: Why is the flash message on successful bookmark creation not displaying at the top of the page right after a successful creation? Shouldn't the flash message handling in my `application.html.erb`take care of it? Could it be due to a syntax error in my `bookmark controller`? 
I also have a question about flash.now vs flash. Is that relevant in this case since the bookmark submission is an AJAX action?

Answer (score 1):

> form of a flash message

Ce ne pas possible avec le [`flash` de `Rails`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#the-flash)

--

The flash forms part of the `session` cookie that Rails populates between actions. This has been notoriously difficult to parse with Ajax, and indeed remains a difficult pattern to implement (how can Rails repopulate the `session` when your browser hasn't been refreshed).

The way to go about it is to pass the value through your ajax method, using [`flash.now`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#flash-now). [Good ref here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23967390/rails-flash-notice-via-ajax) (I wrote about it):

```
#app/controllers/bookmarks_controller.rb
class BookmarksController < ApplicationController
   def create
    @bookmark = Bookmark.new bookmark_params
    @bookmark.user_id = current_user.id

    respond_to do |format|
      if @bookmark.save
        flash.now[:notice] = 'Bookmark was successfully created.'
        format.html { redirect_to user_bookmarks_path }
        format.json { render json: @bookmark, status: :created, location: @bookmark }
        format.js
      else
        flash.now[:error] = "Bookmark could not be created."
        format.html { render :index }
        format.json { render json: @bookmark.errors.full_messages }
        format.js
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Using `flash.now` should allow you to populate the `flash` through Ajax accordingly:

```
#app/views/bookmarks/create.js.erb
$("<%=j flash.now[:notice]  %>").appendTo("#flash-notice")
```