# how to display flash message when layout false

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

My application has two parts. In one part work without layout. In top of the controller has a line layout false. I want to display a flash message in my view when submit my form. but in all flash message tutorials used layout application.html file but in my case i'll not use layout. appreciate your ideas

Comment: You can use that inside page, which working without layout

Comment: Just copy the code for flash messages from layouts/application.html.erb to the desired view file (the one rendered without layout)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use that in two ways

**One** You can use that inside page, which working without layout like

On the top of the page and every page which you need show flash

```
# page.html.erb
<% flash.each do |msg| %>
    <%= msg %>
<% end %>
OR
<% if alert.present? %> # or :notice
   <%= alert %>
<% end %>
```

**Two** This way is more generic like you can create a folder inside view and named `common` inside this create `partial` file and named `_flash.html.erb`

```
# view/common/_flash.html.erb
<% flash.each do |msg| %>
    <%= msg %>
<% end %>
OR
<% if alert.present? %> # or :notice
   <%= alert %>
<% end %>
```

and finally, you can render this on your file which needs to show the message like

On the top of the page and every page which you need show flash

```
<%= render partial: "common/flash" %>
```

Hope to help

Comment: I appreciate your idea. it's work fine. but it works after reload the page.

Comment: You need to implement some js code for this & that's why you need to learn basic ror & js

Comment: @ThilankaUmayangaJayarathna For show flash without page load please see SO answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/27810176/4172515 https://stackoverflow.com/a/23967474/4172515

Comment: Thanks and appreciate. your answer work fine when layout false. I had a misunderstand about flash messages