# How to display validation error in rails using AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

[image]I need to display the validation error of my post model. I have used AJAX call to create a post into the index page of the post. So that when the NewPost button is clicked it will display the new post form partial into the index page. While creating the post in index page if there is any validation errors found, the errors are displayed and it renders the new post form partial in js format again so that the new post form appears twice along with the validation error.

Posts controller:

```
def create
  @post = @topic.posts.build(post_params)
  @post.user = current_user
  respond_to do |format|
    if @post.save
      # Success
    else
      format.js { render 'posts/new' }
    end
  end
end
```

Create.js.erb file:

```js
alert("Post created Successfully");
$('.new_post').hide();
$('.new_one').show();
$('.post_div').prepend('<%= j render @post %>');
```

Index.html.erb file:

```html
<div class="container" >
  <% if params[:topic_id].present? %>
      <h2 align="center"><span class="em-text"><%= @topic.topicname %> Posts</span></h2><hr>
      <%= link_to "New Post", new_topic_post_path, :class => 'btn btn-primary new_one' ,remote: true%> <br><br><br>
   <% else %>      
      <h2 align="center"><span class="em-text">All Posts</span></h2><hr>
    <% end %>
<div class="post_div">
 <%= render @posts %>
</div>
    <%= will_paginate @posts, renderer: BootstrapPagination::Rails %>
</div>
```

Post partial for new post form:

```html
<%= form_for [@topic, @post],remote: true,html: {multipart: true}, url: topic_posts_path do |f| %>

  <% if @post.errors.any? %>
    <% @post.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
      <div class="alert alert-danger"><%= msg %></div>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label "Title" %><br/>
    <%= f.text_field(:title,{:class => 'form-control', :placeholder => 'Enter the Title'}) %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label "Body" %><br/>
    <%= f.text_area(:body, {:class => 'form-control', :placeholder => 'Enter the Post Body'}) %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.submit({:class => 'btn btn-primary'})%>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

new.js.erb file:

```
 $('.new_one').hide().after("<%= j render 'form' %>")
```

Comment: Where is your post form? On what page?

Comment: @JagdeepSingh yes  i have that

Comment: @JagdeepSingh I have mentioned the post partials in the post itself

Comment: @JagdeepSingh now i have edited the post and included th new.js.erb file

Comment: _"I have mentioned the post partials in the post itself"_ - what do you mean?

Comment: @JagdeepSingh Now I have included the _form.html.erb in my question

Comment: Last edit was one hour ago. And the form was already there. I just want to know what page this form in on?

Comment: @JagdeepSingh the form partial that i mentioned here is rendered by new.html.erb and then i have used the ajax call using remote:true into the index page

Comment: @JagdeepSingh please look at the screenshot i provided it is my index page

Comment: Have you tried looking at this similar question?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23967390/rails-flash-notice-via-ajax

Comment: @JagdeepSingh Yeah, but not working in my case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use can like this

```
<% if @post.errors.any? %>
alert("ERROR(S):\n<%= j @post.errors.full_messages.join("\n") %>")
```

Check the post whether it has any errors if error exists alert the error else do something