# Triggering flash notification upon successful update via AJAX - Ruby on Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I want to show the flash success notification upon a successful AJAX update, normally I show the flash notification via the action by,

```
def something

    redirect_to "that_controller_path", :notice => "Success"

end
```

But I have no clue as for how to do this in AJAX success call, my AJAX call is,

```
$.ajax(
      {
      type: "POST",
      url: path,
      data: response1,
      contentType: "application/json",
      success: ->

                 window.location.replace(window.location.protocol + "//" +
                                         window.location.host + "/configuration/manage_users")
                 #Something here!


      });
```

The flash notification is in my application view as,

```
<%if flash[:notice]%>
    <div class="flash_notice">
        <%=flash[:notice]%><br>
    </div><!--  close -->
<%end%>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Ajax**

First of all, I need to explain that you can't pass standard `flash` functionality through the "standard" Ajax flow. Reason being that as the [`flash` is set in a `session cookie`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#the-flash), you will only be able to access these with a browser refresh:

> The flash is a special part of the session which is cleared with each
>   request. This means that values stored there will only be available in
>   the next request, which is useful for passing error messages etc.

You need to enure that when you send / receive ajax, in order to set the `flash` messages, you'll have to cater for them in a different way; either through the `ajax` call itself, or through another method.

--

**Headers**

Admittedly, I've never done this before, but looking at this answer suggests you can [set the headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/366311/how-do-you-handle-rails-flash-with-ajax-requests) in your ajax call:

```
#app/controllers/your_controller.rb
class YourController < ApplicationController
   after_action :flash_headers

   def flash_headers
      return unless request.xhr?
      response.headers['X-Message'] = flash_message
      response.headers["X-Message-Type"] = flash_type.to_s

      flash.discard # don't want the flash to appear when you reload page
   end

   private

   def flash_message
      [:error, :warning, :notice, nil].each do |type|
        return "" if type.nil?
        return flash[type] unless flash[type].blank?
      end
   end

   def flash_type
      [:error, :warning, :notice, nil].each do |type|
          return "" if type.nil?
          return type unless flash[type].blank?
      end
   end 
end
```

I lifted that code from this answer: [How do you handle Rail's flash with Ajax requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/366311/how-do-you-handle-rails-flash-with-ajax-requests)

This sets the *headers* of your request, allowing you to pull this data through your JS:

```
#app/assets/javascripts/application.js.coffee
$(document).on "click", "a", ->
    $.ajax
      type: "POST",
      url: path,
      data: response1,
      contentType: "application/json",
      success: (data) ->
        msg = request.getResponseHeader('X-Message')
        type = request.getResponseHeader('X-Message-Type')

        alert msg #should alert the flash message
```

If this works, it will give you the capacity to set & show the `flash` messages as you wish

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I am using gritter for displaying nice notifications.

So in my application.html.erb I have before my yield:

```
<div id="flash">
  <%= render partial: "shared/notice_banner" %>
</div>
```

In that partial I have:

```
<% flash.each do |key, message| %>
  <%= js add_gritter(message, :title => key.titleize, sticky: false, time: 3000, :image => key) %>
<% end %>
```

In my controller:

```
flash.now[:notice] = "Movie has been deleted."

respond_to do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to root_path }
  format.js
end
```

and finally in my method.js.erb:

```
$("#flash").html('<%= j render partial: "shared/notice_banner" %>')
```

You can see the whole code here:

https://github.com/cristofer/moviedb

I hope it helps

Cheers