# Rails ajax forms + flash messages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

Are there any good tutorials or gems that handle Rails Flash messages via Ajax?

In my .js.erb files, I've used something like the following:

```
<% if @event.errors.any? %>
  <% @event.errors.keys.each do |key| %>
  $( "#event_<%= j key.to_s %>" ).addClass("errorField");
  <% end %>
  $("#flashMSG").css("display", "block");
  if(!$(".flashError").length){
    $("<div class='flashError'>").html("Sorry, please fill in required fields.").appendTo(".noticeContainer");
  }
<% else %>
  $(document).bind("ajax:success", function(e, data, status, xhr) {
    $("#flashMSG").slideUp(400).delay(400).slideDown();
    if(!$(".flashSuccess").length){
      $("<div class='flashSuccess'>").html("Event Updated.").appendTo(".noticeContainer");
    }
  });
<% end %>
```

Just wondering if there's a better way to do this or automate it similar to how Rails just handles it with a standard form submission.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[How do you handle Rail's flash with Ajax requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/366311/how-do-you-handle-rails-flash-with-ajax-requests/10167659#10167659)

and the gist:

https://gist.github.com/linjunpop/3410235